# Are programmatic objects always objects in semantic (language) sense?

Tags: oop

I am not a totally inexperienced programmer but today my head got totally messy when I was figuring a right name for a method. I was programming the game [Battleship](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battleship_%28game%29) and I have started out by making class Board of which simplified version goes like this:

```
class Board:

    SHIP_MISS = 0
    SHIP_HIT = 1
    SHIP_DEAD = 2

    def __init__(self):
        self.ships = [
            [(1,1), (1,2)],
            [(5,6), (5,7), (5,8)],
        ]

    def hit(self, target):
        """ 
        Find out if any ship has been hit or has been sunk and 
        return an appropriate value (one of SHIP_MISS, SHIP_HIT, SHIP_DEAD)
        """
```

Later in my code, I read input coordinates from a user (a shot) and call the hit method like this:

```
# testing if Board works
board = Board()
result = board.hit(coords)
print result
```

Now I got really stuck looking at `board.hit(coords)`. I started wondering if `hit` is really a good name for that method. I was thinking like: "The board is being hit, it is not hitting anything. Should be the method called `process_hit` instead to make it subject in that command? Do I tell objects what to do or do I declare what is done with/to them?" Out of nowhere big mess in my head.

Consider this:

```
 dog.bark()
```

What is `dog` there? Is it a subject of barking? Or an object of barking (does not make sense, does it?).

But this is from a classic example of OOP:

```
 bankAccount.deposit(50)
```

What is `bankAccount` there in language sense? Is it an *object of depositing*, which is common way to think about bank accounts. Or is it a subject, which would mean that it supposed to deposit 50$ to itself.

My question is: Should I think about programmatic objects as objects in language (semantic) sense or should I treat them as subjects and name all their methods accordingly (`process_hit` instead of `hit` in my example). Or are both approaches possible? If so, is it alright to mix them in my code?

(I just hope that this question makes sense.)

Comment: What if `Board` was little more than a collection of `Ship`s, and calling `Board.shotFired(x,y)` called `Ship.wasHit(x,y)` for each remaining ship?  Would that be better?

Comment: @DanPichelman: Well, I feel that these are good names but shotFired is probably even something else than I tried to describe. It is like telling the board that a certain event has occured. I don't how to categorize it atm.

Comment: The best name for that hit method is probably `receive_shot`, I think.

Comment: ok, even better board.evaluate_shot()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting question.  I think a good way of explaining this is to think of Smalltalk (the first *real* OO language). In Smalltalk, everything is an object and the only way that you can communicate with objects is by sending them a message, which is in Java and Python terms invoking a method.

When you send a message to an object, you are telling the object to do something.  To take your example, *you* (ie- the game engine) want to tell the `board` object that a missile has been fired.  The board will then do the right thing and propagate messages to other objects.

So, I agree with you that `hit` is not a proper name for that method.  You are telling the board to do something with a missile that has been fired, so I would go with `handleMissileFired`, (`missileFired` if you want to go shorter, but I tend to like descriptive names).

And as @SamIAM has already mentioned, the terms `subject` and `object` are confusing things here since we are not talking about natural languages. I think the analogy would be that the object receiving the message is always the *subject* since that is the thing doing something.  And any arguments passed in are *objects* since they have things done to them.

Comment: That Smalltalk approach seems like "all methods are handlers", which is nice and simple but I am not sure if it can describe everything. Let's say `list.append(1)`. What is the message here? Is it "Now I am appending number 1 to you, list"?

Comment: You are telling the list to append the number 1 to itself. Method names should be from the point of view of the object that you are calling.

Comment: So you basically command objects around (append, get, set), occasionally you ask them (isActive, isDead), and sometimes you just tell them what happen and expect them to do their job (missileFired, windowFocused). Is there any other common way of interaction?

Comment: I'd classify things a bit differently.  I'd say there are 2 broad classifications of messages.  There are state queries (eg- getters and issers), state transformers (eg- setters and action performers like fireMissile). The two names that you use, missileFired and windowFocused are a bit different.  They are more appropriate for events (eg- an object will broadcast a missile fired event to the world when it has just fired a missile (which can be done through the fireMissile method)).  (ran out of room, see next comment)

Comment: Note the difference between the active and passive voice.  An active verb (fireMissile) implies a method name and a passive name implies an event that is broadcast (missileFired).  Things that are interested in missileFired events would have a handleMissileFired method on it that gets appropriately called by the event bus.  It's complicated and highly subjective.

Comment: And this leads to one of my favorite CS quotes: “There are 2 hard problems in computer science: caching invalidation, naming things, and off-by-1 errors”

Comment: Maybe I would go even for just missileFired for an event handler (the event would be called the same and context would decide). Anyway, I like your approach a lot and your answers really helped me out. I am quite sure now it is correct if I think about objects not just as passive things which are being manipulated but also as things that actually do things (e.g. to other objects or even to itself). `bank_account.deposit(50)` - This seemed strange to me because real bank accounts cannot do depositing but in programming even things like that have processing power, so why not use it.

Comment: But ok, you don't need to stick to interpreting programmatic objects as the active (subject) part in the method call. I can choose that with bank_account.deposit(50) or file.close() I am talking to interpreter (to deposit 50 on that bank_account and close the file) and with dog.bark() I am talking to the dog. It is not like consistent but easier to think about. You always choose the way that is intuitive for you. Nice thing is that others can see it the other way but it doesn't matter. So I guess I'll always just choose what I like (as I always did probably).

Answer (score 3):

You can treat your Objects as Nouns of all kinds.

If you're talking about the literary definition of `object`, as an accusative, `the subject verbed the object` than no, a programming object need not be that kind of object.  It can be a subject too.